# jq_form_remote_tag break

Tags: php, jquery, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I do a `jq_form_remote_tag` and I update a `div`. It is working fine. But under a condition I want to break the update in action and I want to reload the complete page.

How can I stop the `jq_form_remote_tag` and do a complete reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should return a js that will reload the page:

When calling your `jq_form_remote_tag`, add the option `script`. It will interpret the response as javascript.

```
<?php echo jq_form_remote_tag(array(
  'url'      => 'shoppinglist/update',
  'update'   => 'list',
  'script'   => 1,
  'loading'  => jq_visual_effect('fadeIn', '#indicator'),
  'complete' => jq_visual_effect('fadeOut', '#indicator'),
  )) ?>
```

Then, in the template of `shoppinglist/update`, you should return something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.reload()</script>
```

Or directly from the action using:

```
$this->renderText('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.reload()</script>');
```

So, it will fill the `list` element, and then reload the page.